# Xamarin.Forms.Labs Mediapicker hanging on Android trying to pull image from photo library with an Async method

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms here in Xamarin Studio. Trying to make use of Xamarin.Forms.Labs

I have a simple page set up right now with a single button myButton, and beneath it an Image image. So...

```
myButton.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => { var mediaPicker = DependencyService.Get();

if (mediaPicker.IsCameraAvailable)
    {
        var options = new CameraMediaStorageOptions();
        var test = await mediaPicker.SelectedPhotoAsync(options);

        var stream = test.Source;

        if (stream != null)
        {
                image.Source = StreamImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on iOS - image displays in the app the moment one is selected. (If I cancel the selection, I get a crash, but I'll figure that out.) On Android, the app simply hangs. It looks like await on mediaPicker is never finishing up.

Any advice? Getting some basic XF camera/library functionality would be great, and I'm pretty close here.

Pardon if this is poorly formatted. First Stack question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the Android permissions for the app?

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera

> Note: On the Android platform it is necessary to set the
>   CAMERA-Permission, and the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE-Permission in order
>   to make full use of the media services.